# How can i convert a matrix with n columns into a matrix with just one column?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to implement a matlab code in python. 
I have the following case:

MATLAB CODE:

```
    A = a b c d          A=A(:)        A = a
        e f g h                            e 
                                           b   
                                           f
                                           c
                                           g
                                           d
                                           h
```

How can I get the same result in Python, MxN numpy matrix?

Comment: Are you using numpy? And do you really want one column or just flattened — python arrays are row first, so one column would be a bunch of of single-item rows.

Comment: Is this numpy array or python list of list ?

Comment: this is a numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `numpy`,

```
A.flatten()
```

would result in

```
[[a b c d e f g h]]
```

You can use

```
A.transpose().flatten()
```

to get

```
[[a e b f c g d h]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Octave:

```
>> A = 1:8;
>> reshape(A,2,4)
ans =

   1   3   5   7
   2   4   6   8

>> reshape(A,2,4)(:)
ans =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8

>> reshape(A,2,4)(:).'
ans =

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
```

In numpy (ipython)

```
In [11]: A = np.arange(1, 9).reshape(2,4)                                                                    
In [12]: A                                                                                                   
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [13]: A.ravel()                 # ravel is a 'view' if possible                                                                          
Out[13]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])    # shape (8,)
In [14]: A.ravel(order='F')        # default order C                                                                          
Out[14]: array([1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8])
```

`np.ravel` has a good docs.  Also `np.reshape`.

```
In [15]: A.reshape(-1,1)           # (8,1) shape ; octave reshape(A,[],1)                                                       
Out[15]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8]])
In [16]: A.reshape(-1,1,order='F')                                                                           
Out[16]: 
array([[1],
       [5],
       [2],
       [6],
       [3],
       [7],
       [4],
       [8]])
In [17]: A.reshape(-1,1,order='F').T      # transpose                                                                   
Out[17]: array([[1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8]])  # (1,8) shape
```

Key differences:

- Python is order C by default
- Python may be 1d (or even 0)
- no equivalent to (:)  `A[:]` doesn't change things

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you are using numpy, that is highly recomended operating matrix, use reshape:

```py
A.reshape((-1))
# or flatten, as Mark Meyer said
A.flatten()
```

Comment: Wouldn't those methods flatten it to `[a b c d e f g h]` instead of `[a e b f c g d h]`?

Comment: The reshape and flatten methods have a parameter, order:'C' means to flatten in row-major (C-style) order.
    'F' means to flatten in column-major (Fortran-
    style) order. 'A' means to flatten in column-major
    order if `a` is Fortran *contiguous* in memory,
    row-major order otherwise. 'K' means to flatten
    `a` in the order the elements occur in memory.
    The default is 'C'.